# Updating a parent javascript object in iframe and obtaining the updated value in iframe back in the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a document with an iframe in it

```
 <body>
 <script>
  globalObj = {};
  globalObj.myname = 'sachin';
  globalObj.age = '25';
</script>

<form name="PrePage" method = "post" action = "https://scotest.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx"> 
<input type = "hidden" name = "LinkId" value ="ae7263c8-b030-4ca8-9a98-f64308bb2a8e" />                             
<input type = "image" src ="//testcontent.authorize.net/images/donate-gold.gif" />
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
console.log('firts====>');console.log(globalObj);
</script>
<iframe src="iframe.html">

</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('2nd----->');console.log(globalObj);

 </script>
```

**iframe.html**

```
 <html>
  <head>


  </head>
  <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//console.log(parent.globalObj);
//alert('testts-->'+parent.myVar);
    parent.globalObj.myname = 'vikas';
    console.log('updated---->');console.log(parent.globalObj);

</script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

What I want to achieve is,once I update the value in the iframe of the `globalObj` i want to get the updated value back in the parent document and not the orignal value.
How can I achieve it.**The iframe and the html page are on the same domain.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function in your host page:

```
<script>
function updatename(name,age){
  globalObj.name=name;
  globalObj.age=age;
}
</script>
```

Then in your iframe page:

```
<script>
parent.updatename('vikas',23);
</script>
```

You *can* access variables on the host page directly, but be careful with scoping. I always use "document" as the global variable container. In host page:

```
document.globalObj={myname:'sachin',age:23};
```

In iframe page:

```
parent.document.globalObj={myname:'vikas',age:23};
```

Comment: So if I update it in the iframe page and I do access it in the host page will it give me the updated values??I mean I want the same object to be updated and not create two different objects for host and iframe

Comment: This will help me in updating but not solve the issue.I will still get the old values in the host,even if I update those in iframe.

Comment: The iframe page cannot read host page's variables. This is a security consideration even if they are on the same domain. You can propagate host values by reloading the iframe with a parameterized URL.

Comment: So you mean once I update the value in the iframe I won't get the updated values in host?Also,I did not get your parametrized url reload  solution for this.Can you please elaborate.

Comment: setting up full duplex communication between the host and iframe page is tricky. use firebug in firefox to see if you get any access denied errors. changes are your host variables are correctly _set_ by the iframe, but just not _read_ back correctly. if the iframe has an id, say, "ifrm", you can do document.getElementById('ifrm').src="iframe.php?name="+name+"&age="+age;